# What is the fundamental period of 4sin(21t-1)

Tags: signal-processing

From my calculation the fundamental period is $\frac{21\pi}{2
}$ is this correct?

Comment: See Sin x repeats after $2\pi$.Since your x is now $21x$ ,it means period will be cut down 1/21 times.

Answer (score 0):

A general form is given by:

$$\text{a}\cdot\sin\left(\omega\cdot t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

And we know that:

$$\omega=2\pi\text{f}=\frac{2\pi}{\text{T}}\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{a}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\text{T}}\cdot t+\varphi\right)\tag3$$

So, the period is given by:

$$\text{T}=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\tag4$$

> you're not right!

Comment: I used this formula \begin{align}
{\frac{1}{f}}
\end{align} Am I not allowed to use this formula in this case?

Comment: This is how I calculated \begin{align}
{ω}={21}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f={\frac{2π}{ω}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
T={\frac{1}{f}}
\end{align}